# Virtualbox - how to share sybase db on OS Windows installed on Virtualbox

Tags: windows, virtualbox, sybase

I am working on OpenSuse and need to work with sybase on Windows.
I am intreseted is it possible to shared connection to sybase db installed on Windows in Virtualbox. I mean can other lan users connect to this sybase db?

Answer (score 1):

Anyone who can reach the IP address on which the Sybase server is running, can connect to it. It's that simple.